# Extracting Zip File in a Folder

Tags: c#, file, io, zip

I want to extract a zip file and it should check if the zip file has a folder in it. If yes it should extract to the folder called same as the folder in it. and if not it should take the zipfolder name.

My problem is that i always get an exception that a part of a path could not be find but if i open the zip the file is in there.

I despair!

```
private void CreateZipContentFolder(string zipsPath, string destinationPath) {
        Zips = Directory.GetFiles(zipsPath, "*.zip", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
        if (Zips.Count != 0) {

            MyLog.WriteToLog("Creating Folder of ZipFiles... From: " + zipsPath + " To: " + destinationPath, MyLog.Messages.Info);

            foreach (string zip in Zips) {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(zip);
                string dirName = destinationPath + "\\" + fileInfo.Name.Substring(0, fileInfo.Name.Length - 4);

                using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zip)) {

                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries) {

                        if (entry.FullName.EndsWith("/")) {

                            try {
                                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zip, destinationPath);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                MyLog.WriteToLog(e.Message, MyLog.Messages.Error);
                            }
                            break;

                        } else if (new FileInfo(dirName).Exists == false) {

                            try {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
                                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zip, dirName);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                MyLog.WriteToLog(e.Message, MyLog.Messages.Error);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            MyLog.WriteToLog("Created Temporary Folders", MyLog.Messages.Info);
        } else { MyLog.WriteToLog("No Zips Found in: " + zipsPath, MyLog.Messages.Warning); }
    }
```

Update: the exception

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024893

Message=Could not find a part of the path 'P:\Documents_UBS_AM\Projekte\DataCompare\New\package4\AssetPerformance.txt'.

Source=mscorlib

Comment: You are using `FileInfo` to check for Directory when you should be using `DirectoryInfo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some tests for your code, but before - I've made needed refactoring. Your code really needs it. I've removed all "log" lines, but I think - you'll understand how to use it. It should work, but you used some very bad solutions for doing simple things and it could be the reason of your exception.

```
    private void CreateZipContentFolder(List<String> zips, string destinationPath)
    {
        if (zips.Any())
        {
            foreach (string zip in zips)
            {
                string dirName = Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zip));

                using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zip))
                {
                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                    {
                        if (entry.FullName.EndsWith("/"))
                        {
                            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zip, destinationPath);
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (!Directory.Exists(dirName))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
                            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zip, dirName);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And also  could you please provide something like "files' tree" if it does not start to work for you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your great awnser! but it don't work with the same exception. and i know thats not because your code. but i can't find the problem... could i send you like my project its not so big? because i didn't find it the whole day..

Comment: @Ams1 hi, you could upload your project to github for example. But actually, I suppose that you have some problems with file pathes, not with code.

Comment: Yes i found the problem. its because i always made to much \ . but your awnser help me out anyway thanks !